# Recovering files from a decrypted .Private directory

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs

Using Linux Mint 17 Cinnamon 64-bit.

Originally, I asked this on askubuntu - https://askubuntu.com/questions/831300/cannot-see-contents-of-home-directory-after-error-and-restart - and was then told to come here.

I'm on my live USB right now.  I've successfully run `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private`, with the data being sent to `/tmp/ecryptfs.8o5N9a3d`.  The latter is filled with folders I cannot decipher, all named things like `ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.[string of characters]`.  What is the next step in getting these files back to their old, usable state?

I would appreciate any help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the drive is mounted.
Navigate into the folder where the drive is mounted (usually `media`) and copy the mount UUID.
Now fill in your UUID and USERNAME below and execute.

```
sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /media/USERNAME/UUID/home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.Private\
```

It will ask if you wish to recover. If you enter correctly, it will un-encrypt correctly to tmp.